# Working with Nodejs + MSSQL at Ubuntu

Tags: nodejs, sql, odbc

I've my nodejs app connected to MSSQL server, worked perfectly in my Windows laptop, sing [mssql@npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mssql)

The same app is not able to see the database in my Ubuntu laptop.

I defined the mssql connectivity in Ubuntu as below, am I missing any thing?

1. Updated my ~/.profile, as:

> ```
>   ~$ export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
>   ~$ export ODBCSYSINI=/etc
>   ~$ export FREETDSCONF=/etc/freetds/freetds.conf
> ```

2. Logged-out the laptop, to get the above active, and the profile refreshed.
3. Installed the required connectivity packages.

> ```
>   ~$ sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-dev sqsh tdsodbc -y
> ```

4. Configured FreeTDS

> ```
>   ~$ sudo gedit /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
>
>    [ACUMENSERVER]
>    host = 192.168.0.10
>    port = 1433
>    tds version = 7.0
> ```

5. Tested the FreeTDS connection with sqsh, and it works fine:

> ```
>   ~$ sqsh -S ACUMENSERVER -U mssql-username -P mssql-password
> ```

6. Configured ODBC - odbcinst.ini:

> ```
>   ~$ sudo gedit /etc/odbcinst.ini
>
>      [FreeTDS]
>      Description     = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
>      Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
>      Setup           = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
>      CPTimeout       =
>      CPReuse         =
>      FileUsage       = 1
> ```

7. Configured ODBC - odbc.ini:

> ```
> ~$ sudo gedit /etc/odbc.ini
>
>    [ACUMENSERVER]
>       Driver          = FreeTDS
>       Description     = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
>       Trace           = No
>       Servername      = ACUMENSERVER
>       Database        = myDataBase
> ```

8. Tested the ODBC connection with isql, and it works fine:

> ```
> isql -v ACUMENSERVER mssql-username mssql-passward
> ```

When I run my nodejs app (that is working fine in Windows), I got th below error in Ubuntu, considering all the above got done, and checked:

```
{ name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Failed to connect to ACUMENSERVER:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ESOCKET' }
```

What could be the wrong/missing thing here, I'm opened to use another npm package for mssql connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this can work if the IP address of the server is used, server name is not working!

below what worked with me:

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'sql@123',
//  server: 'myServername',  --> Not Working
//  server: 'ACUMENSERVER',  --> Not Working
    server: '6192.168.0.10', // WORKED
    database: 'myDB'
}

sql.connect(config).then(function() { 
// Query 

new sql.Request().query('select top 1 itemcode from OITM').then(function(recordset) {
    console.dir(recordset);
    }).catch(function(err) {console.log(err); /* ... query error checks ... */ });


// Stored Procedure 

new sql.Request()
    .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
    .output('output_parameter', sql.VarChar(50))
    .execute('procedure_name').then(function(recordset) {
         console.dir(recordset);
     }).catch(function(err) {console.log(err); /* ... execute error checks ... */ });



}).catch(function(err) {console.log(err); /* ... connect error checks ... */ });
```